# How to redirect visitor to a custom URL using PHP code in functions.php

Tags: redirect, urls

The users have to be redirected to a custom URL which I already know (its part of the programming logic). I just need to know which WP function to use/ what php code to use to redirect the user to the new URL. This code will be executed within a php function in functions.php--> that function will first do some processing, and then send the user to the new URL

How do I do the above?

Note-- I tried using wp_redirect but it does not work.

This is the code I tried to use (that did not work)--

```
       $redirecturl = get_post_type_archive_link('property');
       echo "\n\n Redirect URL for property posts=" + $redirecturl;
       wp_redirect( "http://" .  $redirecturl + "?post_type=property&search_keyword=" + $search_keyword ;
```

Comment: Edit your post to show us the code you tried that didn't work.

Comment: @CharlesClarkson added code that did not work to the post...

Comment: @CharlesClarkson  wp_redirect only works when no data has already been sent-- i.e. it should be the first thing happening( thats also the reason for the error message "Cannot Modify header information-...." ) hence I cannot use it...

Comment: The echo is the reason for the warning message. You cannot echo something and then redirect using `wp_redirect()`.

Comment: You can use `Output Buffering`, if you really need to `echo` something - take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766353/interview-question-can-we-have-an-echo-before-header

Answer (score 5):

First, it is hard to believe that `wp_redirect` isn't working, below some (example) code how to use it:

```
function wpse101952_redirect() {
  global $post;

    if( /*SOME CONDITIONAL LOGIC*/ ) { //examples: is_home() or is_single() or is_user_logged_in() or isset($_SESSION['some_var'])

        wp_redirect( /*SOME SPECIFIC URL*/ );

        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse101952_redirect' );
```

Second, there would be the question if that is the right approach for your case, but for that to decide you should elaborate on what you are trying to do a little bit more.

---

edit:

The function `get_post_type_archive_link()` gives you the complete permalink, you don't need to add `http://` and `?post_type=property`:

```
   wp_redirect( $redirecturl . "?search_keyword=" . $search_keyword );
```

Answer (score 2):

Running something similar to your code I get this warning in the error log:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /xxx/wordpress/wp-content/themes/balance/functions.php:4) in /xxx/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876
```

When I used this to test:

```
$redirecturl = 'google.com';
wp_redirect( 'http://' .  $redirecturl );
exit;
```

Everything works fine, so you might try:

```
$redirecturl = get_post_type_archive_link( 'property' );
wp_redirect( 'http://' .  $redirecturl . '?post_type=property&search_keyword=' . $search_keyword );
exit;
```

The `exit` code is recommended in the [Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect).